# Function of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Let us consider the following function
$$F(x) = \sum_i \frac{a_i}{x - y_i}$$ 
Is it possible to simplify $F(x)$ so that the repeated sum for each value of $x$ can be avoided ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a finite sum, you can write $$F(x)={{\rm something\ horrible}\over(x-y_1)(x-y_2)\times\cdots\times(x-y_n)}$$ by just putting everything over a common denominator.

If it's an infinite sum, chances are you can't do anything much with it, unless the $a_i$ and $y_i$ are very special.

Answer (score 0):

But its not going to simplify it. Computationally also it will be very expensive. Is there any other way so that one need to sum the series only once and enable to evaluate this function at all other values of x.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I realize you don't yet have enough reputation for comments, but this is meant as an answers area. You could also add an update to the question. Regards